# JPA Criteria API filtering on subclasses' attribute

Tags: jpa, hibernate-criteria

I have the following entity domain.

**Parent class**

```java
@Entity
public final class SupportModuleInteraction implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "supportModuleInteraction")
    @OrderColumn
    private List<Event> events;

    // ... getters/setters/ other attributes ommitted
}
```

**Child class hierachy**

```java
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "event_type")
public abstract class Event implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private SupportModuleInteraction supportModuleInteraction;
}


@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("SEARCH")
public final class SearchEvent extends Event {

    @Lob
    private String searchTerm;
}
```

I'm trying to retrieve any SupportModuleInteractions that contain a SearchEvent containing a keyword.

This is the Specification I'm using to try and retrieve those SupportModuleInteractions:

```java
public static Specification<SupportModuleInteraction> interactionWithSearchEventContaingKeyword(String keyword) {
        return new Specification<SupportModuleInteraction>() {
            @Override
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<SupportModuleInteraction> smi, CriteriaQuery<?> criteriaQuery, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
                Join<SupportModuleInteraction, SearchEvent> events = smi.join("events");
                return criteriaBuilder.and(
                        criteriaBuilder.equal(events.type(), SearchEvent.class),
                        criteriaBuilder.like(events.get("searchTerm"), "%" + keyword + "%"));
            }
        };
    }
```

The Specification fails saying that Event contains no attribute called "searchTerm" which makes sense as that's present only on the SearchEvent subclass.

I've looked at this answer here [JPA2 Criteria queries on entity hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813006/jpa2-criteria-queries-on-entity-hierarchy) which doesn't solve my issue as the entity involved in the query lies outside the class hierarchy.

As a native SQL query, this is what I'm trying to acheive:

```
SELECT *
FROM event E JOIN support_module_interaction smi ON E.support_module_interaction_id = smi.id
WHERE event_type = 'SEARCH'
  AND search_term LIKE 'searchString'
```

**UPDATE 31/08/2019**

I've looked at [JPA Criteria API: query property of subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6903783/jpa-criteria-api-query-property-of-subclass) and revised the Specification to use `criteriaBuilder.treat(...)` with no luck:

```java
 public static Specification<SupportModuleInteraction> interactionWithSearchEventContaingKeyword(String keyword) {
        return new Specification<SupportModuleInteraction>() {
            @Override
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<SupportModuleInteraction> smi, CriteriaQuery<?> criteriaQuery, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
                Join<SupportModuleInteraction, SearchEvent> events = smi.join("events");
                return criteriaBuilder.and(
                        criteriaBuilder.equal(events.type(), SearchEvent.class),
                        criteriaBuilder.like(
                                criteriaBuilder.treat(events.get("searchTerm"), SearchEvent.class).get("searchTerm"),
                                "%" + keyword + "%"));
            }
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The various inheritance strategies in Hibernate are rather difficult to work with in the JPA Crtieria API.

Instead of using `treat()`, which is rather finicky (see [HHH-9862](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9862?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aworklog-tabpanel) and related issues), generate a `subquery()` expression which filters for `searchTerm` and add that to your parent query.

Your overall implementation is unclear, so I created a basic example:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<SupportModuleInteraction> cq = cb.createQuery(SupportModuleInteraction.class);

Root<SupportModuleInteraction> supModIntRoot = cq.from(SupportModuleInteraction.class);
Join<SupportModuleInteraction, Event> supModIntEventJoin = supModIntRoot.join("events"); 

// Instantiate the Subquery and Root objects for your subclass entity
Subquery<SearchEvent> searchEventSubquery = cq.from(SearchEvent.class);
Root<SearchEvent> searchEventRoot = searchEventSubquery.from(SearchEvent.class);
// Generate the subquery and filter based on the given parameter
searchEventSubquery.select(searchEventRoot);
searchEventSubquery.where(cb.like(searchEventRoot.get("searchTerm", "%" + searchTerm + "%");

// add subquery to where clause in parent query
cq.select(supModIntRoot);
cq.where(supModIntEventJoin.in(searchEventSubquery), //other subqueries and filters...);
```